# What is the largest file (in terms of storage space\mb) that can be printed on an Elegoo Saturn?

Tags: file-formats, elegoo-saturn

In terms of Mb, rather than volume, what is the largest file size that the Elegoo Saturn 3D printer is capable of handling in a single print?

How is this limit determined, for example, is it due to a limit on the board, or in the Chitubox file format, or in some other way?

Answer (score 0):

Not an Elegoo Saturn, but an Anycubic printer is my device. I've noted that each layer is loaded from the flash drive moments prior to the burn/flash/print. I suspect this method is used in many printers.

If you consider that even a large LCD panel requires only to present an open path for UV light or a closed path for each pixel, the amount of data required for a full printed layer or a fully empty layer is quite small in terms of bytes.

Non-monochrome LCD panels would use more data, as each pixel is defined in three colors (or none) compared to monochrome (on/off).

I believe that my printer uses the Chitubox board system, making the similarities to yours a valid comparison.

Your limitations would be based on the size of the medium containing the file as well as the physical size of the print.

Comment: And how would I calculate that in MB?

Comment: The most complex data pattern would be incidentally a checkerboard in a bitmap format (jpg), because each pixel is defined separately as it is not the same as the neighbor. Datawise, there is no difference in the picture file if it is shown on monochrome or non-monochrome panel. It is the display driver that turns it into the display's usage format of signals.